# Ordering tags by posts publication date

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm trying to create a list Ghost index page that would list all the tags and the posts in them.

Is there a way to do this without manually looping through posts and figuring out the tags order?

So something like this basically:

```
{{#get 'tags' limit='all' include='posts' order='posts.published_at desc'}}
    {{#foreach tags}}
        <a href='/tag/'>
        <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
        </a>
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this directly in your single call to the `get` helper, but you can try to do this with two calls:

```
{{#get "tags" limit="all" include="count.posts"}}
   {{#foreach tags}}
      // Do tag magic here, then get the posts for the tag
      {{#get "posts" filter="tag:{{slug}}" limit="all" order="published_at desc"}}
          {{#foreach posts}}
            // Do post magic here
          {{/foreach}}
      {{/get}}                     
   {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doesn't solve the problem. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. With the two calls to `get` helper we can list the tags, but still don't know how to order them correctly. Do we know at `tags` foreach loop when a new post were added to a tags?

Comment: OK, I see. Indeed this doesn't solve that. I'm not sure if it can be done with existing capabilities of Ghost; you might have to get creative and use the API with jQuery to display the data or create a custom helper...